# How can I set Google Chrome Canary as the default browser on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome

Normally, Google Chrome Canary cannot be set to be the system's default browser - it shows the following message in its settings:

> This is a secondary installation of Google Chrome, and cannot be made your default browser.

They have good reasons, but nevertheless I want to use it as my default. **How can I set Google Chrome Canary as the default browser on Windows 8?**

I found numerous solutions online about previous Windows versions, all revolving around editing the registry, and unfortunately none of them were able to solve this for me.

Comment: Is there a developmental need to set it as default? Or you want canary to open when you click on hyperlinks?

Comment: @meguroyama the latter.

Comment: Try going into the system's default programs settings and configuring Chrome Canary to open HTTP links by default.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace `YourUsernameHere` with your user name. After that copy and paste the below into a text file and save it as canary.reg. then double click the file.

This will only work if you have administrative privileges on your computer. If you are doing this on a computer without admin, you can use the same setup, replacing `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE` with `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software` and replacing `ChromeSxSHTML` with `ChromeSxSHTML` with the key you can find in Regedit in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\` - You'll see one named `ChromeSSHTML.<some random string here>`. Copy this and replace `ChromeSxSHTML` with it.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\ChromeSxSHTML]
"URL Protocol"=""
@="Google Chrome Canary HTML Document"
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\ChromeSxSHTML\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\Users\\YourUsernameHere\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome SxS\\Application\\chrome.exe,4"
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\ChromeSxSHTML\shell]
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\ChromeSxSHTML\shell\open]
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\ChromeSxSHTML\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Users\\YourUsernameHere\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome SxS\\Application\\chrome.exe\" -- \"%1\""
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\ChromeSxSURL]
@="Google Chrome Canary URL"
"FriendlyTypeName"="Google Chrome Canary URL"
"URL Protocol"=""
"EditFlags"=dword:00000002
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\ChromeSxSURL\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\Users\\YourUsernameHere\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome SxS\\Application\\chrome.exe,4"
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\ChromeSxSURL\shell]
@="open"
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\ChromeSxSURL\shell\open]
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\ChromeSxSURL\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Users\\YourUsernameHere\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome SxS\\Application\\chrome.exe\" -- \"%1\""
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\FirefoxURL\shell\open\ddeexec]
@="\"%1\",,0,0,,,,"
"NoActivateHandler"=""
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\FirefoxURL\shell\open\ddeexec\Application]
@="Google Chrome Canary"
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\FirefoxURL\shell\open\ddeexec\Topic]
@="WWW_OpenURL"
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\http\UserChoice]
"Progid"="ChromeSxSHTML"
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\https\UserChoice]
"Progid"="ChromeSxSHTML"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.htm]
@="ChromeSxSHTML"
"Content Type"="text/html"
"PerceivedType"="text"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.html]
@="ChromeSxSHTML"
"Content Type"="text/html"
"PerceivedType"="text"
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. How do i undo it?

Comment: Came across your post - unfortunately doesn't seem to work anymore with the latest version of chrome canary on windows 7

Comment: This one works for me. http://techdows.com/2012/05/set-chrome-canary-as-default-browser-in-windows.html

Answer (score 45):

Control Panel > Default Programs > Set your default programs. Click on Google Chrome Canary and select "Set this program as default".

Comment: It doesn't appear in the list of programs to choose from and there's no way to browse to add more programs.

Comment: I confirm this works on Windows 8.1. Not sure about other Windows versions.

Comment: It's not working on windows 7

Comment: This does work on Windows XP, however :/

Comment: Can confirm it works on Windows 7 64-bit

Comment: Works fine on Windows 10 Pro

Comment: Worked for me. Windows 7 Enterprise+SP1 x64

Comment: In OSX Yosmite 10.10.3 - System Preferences -> General -> Default web browser (set to Google Chrome Canary)

Answer (score 11):

Not answering the original question, but for people like me who might stumble upon this page when searching, the way to do it on OS X Yosemite (10.10) and up is in System Preferences -> General. Before it was in Safari's setting but now it's no longer the case.

Comment: You could create a new question for OS X Yosemite (10.10) and answer it yourself. Also, you could link that question to this one. But, adding an answer for another question is a wrong approach

Answer (score -1):

On Windows 10:

Settings ➡ System ➡ Default apps ➡ Set defaults by app

Chrome Canary should appear in the list.